# OpenCV (c++) multi channel element access

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the "new" **2.0 c++ version of OpenCV**, but everything is else like in simple C version. I have some problem with changing the values in image.

The image is CV_8UC3.

```
for (int i=0; i<image.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<image.cols; j++)
    {
        if (someArray[i][j] == 0)
        {
            image.at<Vec3i>(i,j)[0] = 0;
            image.at<Vec3i>(i,j)[1] = 0;
            image.at<Vec3i>(i,j)[2] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong???

Thank you!

Comment: Another way, `image(cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)) = cv::Scalar(r,g,b);` if you want to set a specific region with a colour for type `CV_8UC3`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `Vec3b` instead of `Vec3i` ?

`CV_8UC3` means your image is 8 bit, 3 channels, unsigned char. While `Vec3i`is for 3 channels integers and `Vec3b`is for 3 channels unsigned char.

So I think you should be using `Vec3b`