# The results of OpenCV idft() and MATLAB ifft2 does not match

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

So i'm testing my algorithm in MATLAB and it's done.

Then now doing cording for porting on C++ with OpenCV 2.4.5.

The problem is inverse fourier transform methods of two platforms, OpenCV and MATLAB.

So i have tested with simple matrix.

Here's test results.

The subject matrix is... 3 by 3 2-D.

```
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9
```

**-MATLAB-**

```
test = [ 1, 2, 3;
         4, 5, 6;
         7, 8, 9];
```

ifft2(test);

*result*

```
   5.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 - 0.2887i  -0.5000 + 0.2887i
  -1.5000 - 0.8660i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -1.5000 + 0.8660i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

**-OPENCV-**

Note:Elements are same values.

```
Mat a = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
Mat b = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC1);

 a.at<double>(0,0) = 1;
 a.at<double>(0,1) = 2;
 a.at<double>(0,2) = 3;

 a.at<double>(1,0) = 4;
 a.at<double>(1,1) = 5;
 a.at<double>(1,2) = 6;

 a.at<double>(2,0) = 7;
 a.at<double>(2,1) = 8;
 a.at<double>(2,2) = 9;

 idft(a, b, DFT_SCALE, 0);
```

*result*

```
    4.33333     -4.13077     2.79743
   -2.10313     -0.103134   -2.83518
   -0.563533     2.16852     1.43647
```

I still didnt have found the solution. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981100/opencv-dft-inverse-different-from-matlabs-ifft)  couldn't gave me a solution.

*EDIT:* The problem has been solved. I put the CV_64FC1 to idft() as an input and CV_64FC2 as an output. A two matrices must be have same depth, both input and output are have to be 64_FC2. And flags DFT+COMPLEX_OUTPUT+DFT_SCALE is same as MATLAB's ifft2.

**-SOLVED-**

```
Mat input = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC2); 
Mat output = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC2);
idft(input, output, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT+DFT_SCALE, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT+cv::DFT_SCALE` since the input to `idft` clearly results in a complex-valued matrix.

Also, I think you'll need a 2-channel array for the output (type `CV_64FC2`), similarly for the input. As with any [multi-channel image in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817019/opencv-c-multi-channel-element-access), you then access elements with the appropriate vector type (e.g. for doubles, `.at<cv::Vec2d>(i,j)`, where the `Vec2d` stores the real and imaginary components at location `i,j`).

Comment: I just have been tried following your answer. And here's what i got. I 've applied idft(a, b, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT+DFT_SCALE); and b is CV_64F2. After idft 3x3 b turned into 2x2 matrix. b[0] 4.33333 2.79743
-2.10313 -2.83518, b[1] -4.13077 -2.10313 -0.103134 -0.563533. I'm still confused!

Comment: @user3502592 I assume you actually did `CV_64FC2` not `CV_64F2`?

Comment: Yes i actually used CV_64FC2 just typo in here.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use 2 channel input matrices (CV_64FC2) you should use

```
a.at<Vec2d>(0,0)[0] = 1; // Re - part
a.at<Vec2d>(0,0)[1] = 0; // Im - part
```

instead of:

```
a.at<double>(0,0) = 1;
```